# Linq-to-entities in DotNetNuke

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, dotnetnuke

Is it possible to use `linq-to-entities` in `DotNetNuke`? On the other hand can a `c# dotnetnuke development package` be used to develop a `linq-to-entities dotnetnuke web application`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a module template available at http://dnntechtemplate.codeplex.com/ which demonstrates using Entity Framework in a DotNetNuke environment (taking care of the `objectQualifier` and `databaseOwner` configuration automatically).

Answer (score 0):

Version 7 of DNN will start using PetaPoco as an ORM. You should definitely consider using PetaPoco instead of Linq-To-Entities.

http://www.charlesnurse.com/Blog/tabid/226/EntryId/53/DAL-2-A-New-DotNetNuke-Data-Layer-for-a-New-Decade.aspx

Comment: For simple persistence, certainly; however, PetaPoco is currently not very good at handling table relationships. Non-trivial modules likely require as much.

Comment: You're not limited to simple persistence with PetaPoco. You can extend the generated classes, you can use Stored Procedures, you can write custom SQL and do custom bindings. I have yet to run into something that can't be done cleanly with PetaPoco.